# trying to keep some escape characters.. but not others. ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stringbuilder

I am having trouble formatting my string correctly. I am reading strings from a file and trying to use them as js code.

```
file_line = blah'blah"blah
string = line.gsub(/'/, "\\\'").gsub(/"/, "\\\"").dump
```

I want the output to be:

```
blah\'blah\"blah
```

But I cant seem to format it right. I have tried a bunch of things.

Comment: What you have currently is not valid Ruby code, were you just saying that an example line in the file is `blah'blah"blah`? It also appears that your variable `line` is unset but I assume that's what you are pumping the source file into

Comment: You can use the `%q` literal to enter a string with unescaped `'` and `"`: `file_line = %q{blah'blah"blah}`

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: file_line was an example. not actual code.. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a single `gsub` matching both, `'` and `"`, along with a block to prepend a `\`:

```
line = %q{blah'blah"blah}

string = line.gsub(/["']/) { |m| "\\#{m}" }
#=> "blah\\'blah\\\"blah"

puts string
```

Output:

```
blah\'blah\"blah
```

Comment: It's the cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "blah'blah\"blah"
puts string.gsub(/'/,"\\\\'").gsub(/"/,'\"') # => blah\'blah\"blah
```

There's a whole lot of escaping going on here. To be honest I don't really understand the first one, but the second one is simple. I think in the first one we are escaping the backslash we want to add, and then escaping those two backslashes to avoid ruby interpretting them as a reference to the string. Or something. Trying to do a single level of escaping yields this:

```
puts string.gsub(/'/,"\\'").gsub(/"/,'\"') # => blahblah\"blahblah\"blah
```